At least two consecutive 'A's
How many permutations of A,A,A,B,B,C,C,D,D,D contain at least two consecutive 'A's?
My attempt:
The number of permutations with exactly two consecutive 'A's:
$$
W(P_{AA})=\frac{9!}{1!2!2!3!}-2\cdot \frac{8!}{1!2!2!3!}
$$
I took two 'A's into one block, but then I double counted (AA)A and A(AA) so I needed to remove the number of permutations with triple A.
The number of permutations with three consecutive 'A's:
$$W(P_{AAA})=\frac{8!}{1!2!2!3!}$$
The total number of permutations with at least two consecutive 'A's is
$$W(P_{AA})+W(P_{AAA})=\frac{9!}{1!2!2!3!}- \frac{8!}{1!2!2!3!}
$$

Your first step double counted the $AAA$ words,  so you correctly removed one copy of them.  Why would you then add back a copy?

@lulu Because the question asked the number of words with at least two consequent 'A's

But... you miscounted the $AA$ words.  If you make a block as $AA$ then you have $10$ characters,  not $9$

But you already have the $AAA$  words. You had them twice and you subtracted them once,  so they are counted.

@lulu Sorry there should have been only two 'C's (I edited the question)

Do you mean “consecutive” As?

Ok, so then $1!$ should appear twice.  Once for the single $A$ and again for the single $AA$. Not that it changes the value of course.

Thanks @lulu I'll fix the suggestion, It also agrees with Zootopia answer

To confirm my comment on the count, consider words made from three $A's$.  Obviously there is only one word you can make, just $AAA$.  But do it your way.  Making a block $AA$ there are two words, $A(AA), (AA)A$.  Now you subtract $1$, for the $AAA$ word, getting the correct answer, $1$.  But if you then add it back, you get the incorrect answer, $2$.

Do you want words only of length $10$?

@lulu can you explain Zootopia solution?

@RobPratt Yes, only words of length 10

Place the $A's$ in a line.  That leaves four gaps.  The inner two must be at least $1$, the outer two could be $0$. Let $g_1, g_2, g_3, g_4$ be the gaps. Then $g_1+g_2+g_3+g_4=7$. Then let $G_2=g_2-1$, and $G_3=g_3-1$.  Thus $g_1+G_2+G_3+g_4=7-2=5$  Use Stars and Bars to count the number of solutions, then populate them.

Thanks lulu....

Total number of words that can be formed  are $\displaystyle\frac{10!}{3!×2!×2!×3!}=X$
Total number of words with alternate $A's$ are $\displaystyle\frac{\binom{8}{3}×7!×3!}{3!×2!×2!×3!}=Y$
Number of desired words are $X-Y$

We want no two $A's$ together, so they have to come in between of other letters. There will be $8$ places available, we'll choose any $3$ places and then arrange them.

Can you explain how you calculated $B$ ?

@RobPratt done

Another approach: Grab a pair of $A$’s and treat them as a block. It can be set into a 10-space row in $9 \choose 1$ ways. Then the remaining $A$ has $8 \choose 1$ spaces it can occupy. We can then deposit the $B$’s  in $7 \choose 2$ ways, which leaves $5 \choose 2$ ways to distribute the $C$’s, and then there is only $3 \choose 3$ way to seat the $D$’s.
But of course this overcounts because each $AAA$ gets counted once  for $AA,A$ and again for $A,AA$. So subtract the number of permutations in which the three $A$’s are contiguous, which is ${8 \choose 1}{7 \choose 2}{5 \choose 2}{3 \choose 3}$.
